# How can I update values in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuples looking like this:

```
[(5, 0, 1, 8), (5, 0, 1, 14, 15), (5, 0, 1, 14, 16)]
```

I also have a dictionary that is in the form:

```
{0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3: [], 4: [], 5: ['CVE-2016-3379'], 7: ['CVE-2016-3646'], 8: [], 9: ['CVE-2015-1769'], 10: ['CVE-2016-3364', 'CVE-2016-7193', 'CVE-2016-3363'], 14: [], 15: ['CVE-2015-1769'], 16: ['CVE-2016-3363', 'CVE-2016-7193', 'CVE-2016-3364'], 17: [], 18: [], 19: [], 20: [], 21: ['CVE-2015-1769'], 22: ['CVE-2016-3363', 'CVE-2016-7193', 'CVE-2016-3364'], 26: [], 27: [], 28: [], 29: [], 30: [], 32: []}
```

How can I update the values in the first list with the values from the dictionary?

I want `5` for example to become `5: ['CVE-2016-3379']`, `0` to become `0: []` etc.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried.  SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Please put that info in your question, where it belongs. And it's pointless putting multi-line Python code into comments since the indentation gets lost.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is not a coding assisgnment, it is a part of a project that is confidential and my python skills are not that great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with this [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
res = [tuple('{}: {}'.format(i, my_dict[i]) for i in t) for t in my_list]
```

**Example of output:**

```
>>> my_list = [(5, 0, 1, 8)]
>>> my_dict = {0: [], 1: [], 5: ['CVE-2016-3379'], 8: []}
>>> res = [tuple('{}: {}'.format(i, my_dict[i]) for i in t) for t in my_list]
>>> res
[("5: ['CVE-2016-3379']", '0: []', '1: []', '8: []')]
```

Comment: Quite possible that this is what the OP means by his desired output :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your `list` is called `lst` and the `dict` is called `dct`, you can use the following nested comprehension:

```
lst = [tuple(dct[x] for x in tpl) for tpl in lst]
```

Since the tuples in your `list` are immutable, you can not just update their cells. You have to rebuild them with the new values.